# Results from a manyToOne, oneToMany association in Symfony2 not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using symfony2 to build my web app but I cannot figure out why a query will not return results from two tables, just one. In my results I am only getting back the value from the **SupplierPayment** table.

I have 1 tables that looks like this:

**SupplierPayment**

```
 id | 
 ------
 1  |
```

I have another table that looks like this:

**SettlementReport**

```
 id | SupplierPayment
 ------------------------------
 1  | 1

 SupplierPayment is a manyToOne association back to the SupplierPayment table.
```

Here are my associations for each respective entity:

**SupplierPayment Entity**

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="WIC\SettlementBundle\Entity\SettlementReport", mappedBy="supplierPayment", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 */
protected $settlementReport;
```

**SettlementReport Entity**

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\SupplierBundle\Entity\SupplierPayment", inversedBy="supplierReport")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="supplierPayment_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
protected $supplierPayment;
```

I would like it to return the value from the SupplierPayment with the results from the SettlementReport.

For some reason when use doctrine to query my SupplierPayment table using a ->find(1)
it does not include the results from the **SettlementReport** table. Why is that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\SupplierBundle\Entity\SupplierPayment", inversedBy="supplierReport")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="supplierPayment_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
protected $supplierPayment;
```

Fix:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\SupplierBundle\Entity\SupplierPayment", inversedBy="settlementReport")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="supplierPayment_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
protected $supplierPayment;
```

I Suggest You Use Plural Name For Properties That Hold Many Value(Are ArrayCollection)

Use: "$settlementReports" Instead Of "$settlementReport"

Answer (score 0):

The inversedBy statement need to match to OneToMany propritie of the associated entity
Change inversedBy="supplierReport" to inversedBy="settlementReport"

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\SupplierBundle\Entity\SupplierPayment", inversedBy="settlementReport")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="supplierPayment_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
protected $supplierPayment;
```